# Error navigating to detail page after paths.rb update using Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I have the following Cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario: find vegetable with same color
  Given I am on the details page for "Potato"
```

Since I'm able to piggy back off a web_step:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

All I have to do is and to the paths.rb file which I did:

```
def path_to(page_name)
  case page_name

  when /^the edit page for "(.*)"$/
    edit_vegetable_path(Vegetable.find_by_name($1))
  when /^the details page for "(.*)"$/
    vegetable_path(Vegetable.find_by_title($1))
```

However, once I run cucumber, I get the following error:

```
Given I am on the details page for "Potato"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
      undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
      ./app/views/vegetables/show.html.haml:14:in `_app_views_vegetables_show_html_haml___295190995_93073700'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
```

etc...

I'm not sure why edit_vegetable_path works, but vegetable_path doesn't.  I even tried hard-coding a particular vegetable page (just as a test) and I got the same error:

```
when /^the details page for "(.*)"$/
    '/vegetables/1'
```

I have no idea how to further debug this issue at this point.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was an issue with my view file.  Once I made the change, everything worked out.